# What happens to Ethereum transaction mined into an orphaned block?

Tags: ethereum, nonce

In case if an Ethereum transaction was mined into an orphaned block:

1. Would it still make it into a different "confirmed" block, or it would be reverted?
2. Can this disrupt the nonce sequence of transactions in the confirmed blocks? For example, can we get transactions with reverse order of nonces in different blocks? (transaction with nonce 1 in block 10 and transaction with nonce 0 in block 11)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. It should be asked on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Comment: I disagree @cello, this mechanism is affecting software design and programming for blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

1. The longest chain is the source of truth.
2. Orphaned blocks (aka uncle blocks) are valid blocks that are **not** part of the longest chain.

Even though the transaction has been included in an orphaned block, it is not part of the longest chain. Which means it's not mined yet, state changed resulting from this transaction have not been accepted by the network, and it can be still included in a "confirmed" block.

Applied to your example from point 2: The "transaction nonce 0" has not happened yet, even though it's part of an orphaned block. So it can be mined in some next block. And because it has lower nonce, it has to be executed before the "transaction nonce 1".

Comment: Thanks Petr Hejda, so you mean the correct nonce order is guaranteed in the confirmed blocks, no matter what.